# Height of tableView's header

Tags: javafx, tableview

I am trying to print a TableView, and because it cannot fit in one A4 page, I want to split it in many pages, using number of records (rows), row height, and header height.

Now my problem is how to get the height of the header ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
double height = table.lookup(".column-header-background").getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
```

This will only work after layout has been performed on the table, and after any CSS has been applied.