# JavaFX: onCssApplied?

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

Is there some method to detect when CSS is being applied? Of course if something as convenient as `onCssApplied` event would definitely be most ideal, but I don't think it exists at all. Is there any workaround for this?

### Edit

Well, I definitely have numerous times in these past 2 months that I have situations which made me think if I could detect when CSS is applied. Currently, I still have one which I have yet figured out a workaround.

I have a `TableView`, and I want it to resize its height to fit the number of rows it has. I have followed this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27949038) with some modifications.

The original formula is `fixedCellSize * (rows + 1.01)`, but I have changed it to `fixedCellSize * rows + 25`, which I have assumed the height of header row to be `25`.

However, I do have another constraint which made this solution not ideal.

My application is designed to run on screens of various resolutions, and it has many windows. To make the sizing constant, I have made the root element of all scenes use a calculated font size, which would affect all `em` sizes in all descendent nodes. This change would bring a change in the height of the header row, which would make assumption of `25` px wrong.

Then, I saw another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35255880) that you (James_D) have made in the past. This would allow me to get the reference of the header row node (I assume), and get the size right from it.

The down side is again, I need CSS to be applied, in order to get this reference.

Comment: Not that I know of. I believe CSS is usually applied on the first layout pass on which a control is laid out (unless you call `applyCSS()` explicitly). Can you provide a use case (i.e. why do you want this)? Perhaps there's another way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @James_D Made an edit :)

Comment: Ah, that use case... I've never really come up with a good solution for that. However, once you know the table view has been added to a scene, you can do this by hand: call `tableView.applyCSS(); tableView.layout();` and then you will be able to access the header via a lookup and measure its size.